# Python Class unweighted graph class methods

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods

I'm trying to create a method to add keys and values to my dict (nodes)
the key is the node to the unweighted graph and the values are the connections.

```
class graph:
   def __init__(self,size):
       self.nodes = {}

    def __str__(self):
    return pprint.pformat(self.nodes)
    pass

    def key(self,nodes):  #method for adding keys
       return self.nodes()

    def value(self,nodes): # method for adding values
       pass       


graph1 = graph
graph1.key [1] = []
graph1.value [1] = [1,2]
print(graph1)
```

At the moment the graph.key [1] = [] or graph.value [1] = [1,2] obviously doesn't work as I'm not sure what to put into the method key or value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to come to grips first with python dictionaries, which are associative arrays, or key-value **pairs**. You are trying to accomplish something contrary to the meaning of "dictionary" inside your class, i.e. defining key and value separately. Read up on python dictionaries, code some short examples, and then rethink your class. A class like that, in its simplest form, would probably have attributes like a variable 'points_list', method 'connect_dots', etc. - depending on how you want to use it. It's not really clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish, that's why it got down-voted - but I am guessing that's what you are getting at.